# NullPointerException when running gradlew.bat for GCM sample

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I am running the sample code for gcm provided by Google. When i run the following command : \gradlew.bat run -Pmsg="Rishab" to broadcast message to my android device, it give the following exception :

> G:\GitRepo\google-services\android\gcm>gradlew.bat run -Pmsg="Rishab"
>   Found corrupted package.xml at E:\Applications\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-21\package.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

I have included the API Key in the GCM server and followed every step as stated in the documentation. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: So use \gradlew.bat run -Pmsg="Rishab" --info.

Comment: Parsing E:\Applications\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-21\package.xml
Found corrupted package.xml at E:\Applications\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-21\package.xml
Parsing legacy package: E:\Applications\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-21

Comment: This is the error after running the command with --info

Comment: You should find the error log.